# ToUpper() com acentos

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Possuo uma `string`, onde desejo retorná-la  em maiúscula, para padronizar as informações. Estou utilizando o `ToUpper()`. Porém, quando essa `string` possui acentos o texto fica embaralhado.

Como receber o texto com acentos normais, ou retirar os acentos e receber o texto corretamente?

Minha View chamando a `string`:

```
insira o códig@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sLotacao).ToString().ToUpper()
```

Resultado na página:

```
SECRETARIA M. DE EDUCA&#231;&#227;O
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experimente especificar uma informação de cultura, passando um objeto [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) para o método `ToUpper`:

```
insira o código @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sLotacao).ToString().ToUpper(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR"))
```

Ainda assim, se não funcionar, experimente simplesmente não usar `@Html.DisplayFor`.